# find pid from port over Google TV (Android non-rooted device)

Tags: java, android, port, pid

I'm trying to find the ports being used by a pid over Android's non-rooted GoogleTV (Sony) device.

Unfortunately, all the "netstat -p" ,lsof ,/proc//fd are being blocked.
Is there any other way I can match between a given port on /proc/net/tcp to its pid?

yuval

Answer (score 0):

Chances are high that there is no API which you could use to accomplish this. What /proc/net/tcp and friends are telling you interesting are the inode numbers. The problem is that you just can't resolve them to a socket unless you are able to take a look at /proc/PID/fd. There may be a rather hidden api via ioctl or another syscall to resolve some infos about a inode but I don't realy think there is any.

On the other side this is definitively a linux feature as it encapsulates the users from each others correctly and doesn't leak "system critical" data.